# Realoading an Iframe on blur, mousout or...?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to figure out a way to reload an iframe when it goes out of view using a jQuery slider.  I have posted an example of this here...

http://jsfiddle.net/HG5eX/10/

The iframe appears when you mousover the square but I want the iframe to reload if it goes back down.  Can someone tell me if this is even possible?

Everything you need is on the jsfiddle page but since it's requiring me to put in some code, here is the html part of it...

```
<div style="width:550px; padding:40px 0 0;margin:0 auto; position:relative;">    

    <div id="foo">
        <div id="bar">
<iframe name="popupFrame" src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/het-scherm-van-tv-van-de-test-9015949.jpg" frameborder="0" width="400" height="307" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Is your website and the iframe on the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your iframe and your parent website are in the same domain,

You can try,

```
$("#clickk").hover(function () {
    $("#monster").slideToggle("slow");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('iframe[name="popupFrame"]').attr("src", $('iframe').attr("src"));
});
```

or

```
$("#clickk").hover(function () {
    $("#monster").slideToggle("slow");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    document.getElementsByName('popupFrame')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();
});
```

I doubt this would work in JSFiddle. It wont allow access.

**Note :**

The above would work only if the code in running on the parent.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know how it works.

Comment: tried both of those...  the popup window just went balistic and started sliding up and down on its own as if possessed by the devil or something.  lol

Comment: And we have us a winner!  Thanks.  Appreciate the help.